# Google Tag Manager V5.0 in iOS framework along with Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, google-tag-manager

I am trying to add GTM(V5.0) as dependency for my iOS framework.  After converting GoogleAnalytics to framework, I was able to build my framework. I have added container folder along with the GTM-XXX.json file to the project. But when I try to run the app using the framework it crashes with below exception.

```
    frame #0: 0x000000010b403939 CoreFoundation`CFStringGetLength + 9
    frame #1: 0x0000000108610904 JavaScriptCore`JSStringCreateWithCFString + 36
    frame #2: 0x000000010859b315 JavaScriptCore`-[JSContext evaluateScript:withSourceURL:] + 37
    frame #3: 0x000000010a91d6be testSDK`-[TAGRuntime initWithContainerId:resource:hitStore:dispatchScheduler:] + 454
    frame #4: 0x000000010a9136f6 testSDK`__55-[TAGContainer handleLoadOfContainerData:errorMessage:]_block_invoke + 305
    frame #5: 0x000000010b00e978 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    frame #6: 0x000000010b0380cd libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 8
    frame #7: 0x000000010b015e17 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 236
    frame #8: 0x000000010b016b4b libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_invoke + 1073
    frame #9: 0x000000010b01702b libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 683
    frame #10: 0x000000010b019385 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_root_queue_drain + 720
    frame #11: 0x000000010b019059 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_worker_thread3 + 123
    frame #12: 0x000000010b3e14de libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 1129
    frame #13: 0x000000010b3df341 libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 13
```

GTM works fine when included directly into a target app instead of a framework.  Has anyone successfully used GTM in a iOS dynamic framework? Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I have same issue with GTM iOS SDK 6. It seems Google guys never care about developer experience.